# Formatting integer variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Data being imported to DE as a decimal, needs to be a number in the email so we've got the following code to change it from a decimal to an integer:

```
%%[
SET @number = number
SET @Index = Indexof(@number, '.')
SET @Integer = Substring(@number, "1", Subtract(@Index, 1))
]%%
```

So if number = 1234.00, @Integer = 1234 in the email.

I need it to render as 1,234

thought I could FormatNumber(@Integer, "N0", "en-US") but that didn't work.

thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

```
%%[
SET @decimal = 1234.00
SET @formatted = FormatNumber(@decimal, "F0")
]%%

%%=v(@formatted)=%%
```

outputs `1234`

Snippet: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/Cw1wWNkI

Docs: https://ampscript.guide/formatnumber/

Edit:

With 1000 separator:

```
                         
%%[
SET @decimal = 1234.00
SET @formatted = FormatNumber(@decimal, "N0","en-US")
]%%

%%=v(@formatted)=%%
```

outputs: `1,234`

Snippet: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/9VA0ocyF

docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: OP wants the output to have a thousands separator.

Comment: whoops :D edited a second option. And no, I didn't downvote you ;)

Comment: Nice! I'll delete my answer, yours is way more elegant.